QML: How to recall a submodel in qml file and register classes in main.cpp
I am working on a QML project with classes implementing models with submodels.
I came across this question, where a good solution seemed to be proposed:
Split a QAbstarctListModel into sub models
I am just wondering how to recall the submodel in the qml file, as well as how to register the classes in main.cpp file.
Thanks for any idea offered as a solution for this task.
I am working on an application for managing musical instruments.
The concept I am trying to model are:

item: single piece of gear;
setlist: collection of items;
setlists: collection of setlists.


Item.h

#define ITEM_H

#include \<QObject\>

class Item : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString category READ category WRITE setCategory NOTIFY categoryChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString subcategory READ subcategory WRITE setSubcategory NOTIFY subcategoryChanged)

public:
explicit Item(QObject \*parent = nullptr);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &newName);
    
    QString category() const;
    void setCategory(const QString &newCategory);
    
    QString subcategory() const;
    void setSubcategory(const QString &newSubcategory);

signals:
void nameChanged();
void categoryChanged();

    void subcategoryChanged();

private:
QString m_name;
QString m_category;
QString m_subcategory;
};

#endif // ITEM_H\


Setlist.h

#define SETLIST_H

#include \<QObject\>
#include \<qabstractitemmodel.h\>
#include "Item.h"

class Setlist : public QAbstractListModel
{
Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Item> gear READ gear WRITE setGear NOTIFY gearChanged)

public:
enum Role {
SetlistNameRole,
ItemNameRole,
ItemCategoryRole,
ItemSubcategoryRole
};

    explicit Setlist(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    
    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &newName);
    
    QList<Item> gear() const;
    void setGear(const QList<Item> &newGear);

signals:
void nameChanged();
void gearChanged();

private:
QString m_name;
QList\<Item\> m_gear;

    // QAbstractItemModel interface

public:
virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
virtual QHash\<int, QByteArray\> roleNames() const override;
};

#endif // SETLIST_H


ModelItem.h

#define MODELITEM_H

#include \<QObject\>
#include "Setlist.h"

class ModelItem : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(Setlist* setlist READ setlist WRITE setSetlist NOTIFY setlistChanged)

public:
explicit ModelItem(QObject \*parent = nullptr);

    Setlist *setlist() const;
    void setSetlist(Setlist *newSetlist);

signals:
void setlistChanged();
private:
Setlist \*m_setlist = nullptr;
};

#endif // MODELITEM_H


Setlists.h

#define SETLISTS_H

#include \<QObject\>
#include \<qabstractitemmodel.h\>
#include "ModelItem.h"

class Setlists : public QAbstractListModel
{
Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QList<ModelItem> setlists READ setlists WRITE setSetlists NOTIFY setlistsChanged)

public:
enum Role {
//SetlistNameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
ItemsRole
};

    explicit Setlists(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    
    QList<ModelItem> setlists() const;
    void setSetlists(const QList<ModelItem> &newSetlists);

signals:
void setlistsChanged();
private:
QList\<ModelItem\> m_setlists;

    // QAbstractItemModel interface

public:
virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
virtual QHash\<int, QByteArray\> roleNames() const override;
};

#endif // SETLISTS_H```

